# Finding minimum value based on unique and exhaustive combination of two or more variables

Tags: r, matching

I am trying to identify minimum value based on the unique combination of two variables.

```
id.x  id.y    dist
7     1       4294.25
7     2       2405.00
7     3       4868.00
12    3       3593.00
13    2       4868.00
13    6       5058.00
```

I am already aware of the code using data.tables packages, which can help find the minimum based on one id variable.

```
matchedDT <- DT[ ,.SD[which.min(dist)], by = id.x]
```

Output of this code is does not exhaust the id.y variable, by which I mean that there is one to many relationship between id.x and id.y with a minimum dist at output. Output would be something like -

```
  id.x  id.y    dist
7     2       2405.00
12    3       3593.00
13    2       4868.00
```

What I want to get is if a value of id.y is uniquely consumed in one pair for a minimum value then that value shouldnt be available for another pair. Desired output will be -

```
id.x  id.y    dist
7     2       2405.00
12    3       3593.00
13    6       5058.00
```

As a background, I am trying to find minimum Euclidean distance between data points corresponding to  id.x and id.y, and I want to find the minimum distance between id.x and id.y.

Comment: I think you can use [`widyr`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/widyr)'s `pairwise_dist()` with `upper = FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've fully understood the OP's requirement but the following code returns the expected result for the given input data:

```
DT[, .SD[which.min(dist)], by = id.y][, .SD[which.min(dist)], by = id.x]
#   id.x id.y dist
#1:    7    2 2405
#2:   12    3 3593
#3:   13    6 5058
```

It first finds the rows with minimum distance for each `id.y`:

```
DT[, .SD[which.min(dist)], by = id.y]
#   id.y id.x    dist
#1:    1    7 4294.25
#2:    2    7 2405.00
#3:    3   12 3593.00
#4:    6   13 5058.00
```

which contains duplicates for `id.x`. In a second step, the rows the minimum distance for each `id.x` are retrieved.

This might work just by chance for this small sample data set and needs to be verified with production data.